# Marking Countries Based on Designation and Same Role Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a SQL scenario with a table structure as described below:

| Role | designation | countries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HR | Director | United States |
| HR | Advisor | United States |
| HR | Senior Assistant | India |
| HR | Assistant | Argentina |
| HR | Assistant | United States |
| IT | Director | Japan |
| IT | Alternative Director | Japan |
| IT | Advisor | United Kingdom |

**Specific Requirement:**
I'm trying to create a SQL query to mark countries in the 'condition_color' column based on the following conditions:

If the 'designation' is 'Director' and the same country appears for any other designation in the same role, mark it as 'Red-[country name]'.
Otherwise, display the country name as is.

**Current Approach:**
I've attempted the following query:

SELECT
role,
designation,
countries,
CASE
WHEN designation = 'Director' AND
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test_data e2
WHERE e.role= e2.role
AND e2.designation <> 'Director'
AND e.countries = e2.countries)
THEN CONCAT('Red-', countries)
ELSE countries
END AS condition_color
FROM test_data e;

However, it doesn't yield the expected output. It marks only if the country appears with a different designation rather than considering any designation other than 'Director' in the same country under the same role.

**Desired Output:**
The expected output I'm aiming for is as follows:

| Role | designation | countries | condition_color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HR | Director | United States | Red-United States |
| HR | Advisor | United States | Red-United States |
| HR | Senior Assistant | India | India |
| HR | Assistant | Argentina | Argentina |
| HR | Assistant | United States | Red-United States |
| IT | Director | Japan | Red-Japan |
| IT | Alternative Director | Japan | Red-Japan |
| IT | Advisor | United Kingdom | United Kingdom |

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I changed your text to a markdown table for good reason.

Comment: What is your question here exactly? Why is Advisor in the United States?  How do you know that they aren't in India or Argentina?

Comment: Actually need consider only Director designation is which country same country comes other designation then we should show red color in country this is my requirement.

Comment: Then why is the IT Advisor in the United Kingdom and not Japan..? Where does that value come from..?

Comment: Apologies! In the case where 'Advisor' appears in any roles, we should only consider it if there is any role under the designation 'Director' in the same country. If the same country name exists under any designation of the same role, it should be marked as 'Red-[country name]'; otherwise, it should just display the country name. I hope this clarifies. Your response is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: No, it's not clear. I suggest you take the time to [edit] the question to make it clear. Describe the logic, demonstrate your attempts, explain why they aren't working, *ask* a question. Give us *all* the information needed to answer your (currently) unasked qusetion. We don't have access to your system, so we can't infer your data.

Comment: Hi please check now. now i hope you ill got, what i try to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression here and a windowed count to check to see if you find the director. If you do, you can concatenate `Red-` to the Country's name:

```sql
SELECT [Role], --Role is a reserved keyword and should not be used for object/column names
       Designation,
       Countries, --Why is this plural when it can only be a single value; should be called "Country"
       CONCAT(CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE Designation WHEN 'Director' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY [Role], Countries) > 0 THEN 'Red-' END, Countries)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/En6kRdmX)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a `CASE` statement in SQL.

```
SELECT
    Role,
    designation,
    countries,
    CASE
        WHEN Role = 'HR' AND designation = 'Director' AND countries = 'United States' THEN 'Red-United States'
        WHEN Role = 'HR' AND countries = 'United States' THEN 'Red-United States'
        WHEN Role = 'IT' AND (designation = 'Director' OR designation = 'Alternative Director') AND countries = 'Japan' THEN 'Red-Japan'
        ELSE countries
    END AS condition_color
FROM your_table_name;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
Sorry. country name dynamically come so we need to consider role and designation is 'Director' what country name appear in director row then check other designation same country name or not if same sould mention red-countryname else country name this is i expecting